# javascript - restoring scroll position does not happen

Tags: javascript

```
function getScrollTop()
{
    if(typeof(window.pageYOffset) === 'number')
    {
        // DOM compliant, IE9+
        window.scrollY = window.pageYOffset;
    }
    else
    {
        // IE6-8 workaround
        if(document.body && document.body.scrollTop)
        {
            // IE quirks mode
            window.scrollY = document.body.scrollTop;
        }
            else if(document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop)
        {
            // IE6+ standards compliant mode
            window.scrollY = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        }
    }
}

function getScrollLeft()
{
    if(typeof(window.pageXOffset) === 'number')
    {
        // DOM compliant, IE9+
        window.scrollX = window.pageXOffset;
    }
    else
    {
        // IE6-8 workaround
        if(document.body && document.body.scrollLeft)
        {
            // IE quirks mode
            window.scrollX = document.body.scrollLeft;
        }
        else if(document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollLeft)
        {
            // IE6+ standards compliant mode
            window.scrollX = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        }
    }
}

 // Summed-Up
function imgButtonClick()
{
    getScrollTop();
    getScrollLeft();
    /*Some simple hidden code*/
    window.scroll(window.scrollX, window.scrollY);
}
```

The getScrollTop() and getScrollLeft() functions are obtained from Internet - in a legal way, but the simple code addition does not work ( scroll(window.scrollX, window.scrollY); ). Mozilla's Developer Tools' Web Console (in Firefox) does not show errors. However, once filled with constants in place of scrollX and scrollY global variables - it does the simplified functioning by scrolling the page. The rest of the code, which had not been shown in this post - functions as asked. Other global variables on the page are also performing as asked.

Comment: forgot to add - scrollX and scrollY variables had been initialized, which is not shown in the code provided.

Comment: Better late than never - must be a ban on custom code for me, since it worked later, **same code. Same problem other PCs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to animate a scrolling effect, you will need some additional code to animate the scrolling of the page. Here are some example functions to set the scroll location instantaneously:

```
function scrollToElement(element, scrollToTop)
{
    var element = document.getElementById(element);
    var elLoc = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    var topCoord = elLoc.top + (scrollToTop ? window.innerHeight : 0);
    console.log("About to scroll to: " + topCoord + ":" + elLoc.left);
    window.scroll(elLoc.left, topCoord);
}

function scrollBackToTop()
{
    window.scroll(0,0);   
}
```

If you are looking to animate your scrolling effect, check out these:

[Click here for a javascript solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984604/scroll-a-page-using-javascript).

[Click here for a css solution](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/).

You can also accomplish this using one line of code anywhere in your application or project using jQuery with no plugins:

```
$('html, body').animate(
{
    scrollTop: $("#target-element").offset().top
}, 1000);
```

Taken from [here](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-without-a-jquery-plugin-2/).

Comment: Oh, but the scroll values are being applied to scroll page only after code that gets page scrolled back to top. If you would, please tell me what is not sufficient here. Sincerely, HaarWavelet.

Comment: Updated the answer with a simple function I wrote that retrieves a location of an element (in this case an image) and then scrolls to it's location.

Comment: The "click here to scroll down" button does not seem to function, and you used the same functions as I to obtain the scroll positions. How is that helpful? Edit: added word 'I' in a sentence.

Comment: It scrolls down to the top of the image, but since your original code was relative to the window, this code was written to the window also. Click the button that says "Run code snippet" then click the "Full page" button on the right of the stackoverflow preview. It should work, I've changed the code to show the coordinates in your console.

Comment: I did what you said (also prior to writing my previous comment), but to the same result. However, the alert does provide the screen coordinates. z-index property is being used in full code to hide/reveal image/image button, and that part of code works fine, yet the restoration of scroll positions does not.

Comment: Give me a minute, and I'll put together something more comprehensive.

Comment: Fixed a bug in the answer, modified some of the code.

Comment: Added another function that scrolls back to the top, you now have a function that scrolls to any element on a page, and one that scrolls back to the top, if there is anything mroe specific, just describe what you are trying to do and I will try to add it in there.

Comment: Ok, I have to obtain the scroll coordinates prior to changing z-index value for two elements, then change z-index value for two elements, and then scroll back to the position on the page, for which the coordinates had been obtained. Your code snippet on my computer, in Firefox did not begin to scroll on the click of the button 'click here to scroll down'. If you have a way to provide sentence answer, not code answer to my topic, then please do.

Comment: First what version of Firefox are you using (I'm using 35).

z-index is a CSS property that tells the browser which element to display at the "front" of your page. Changing the z-index would not result in any scrolling of your page.

Comment: My Firefox's version is well beyond 40. And how did you come to conclusion that I said that z-index in the full code was used to scroll page? In the topic's code section I clearly wrote that the functions to record scroll values were called prior to some code, then the some code (changes z-index values), then window.scroll(window.scrollX, window.scrollY);. If you have anything on the issues stated in the topic, then fell free to respond appropriately.

Comment: I misunderstood your inclusion of that property, apologies. Given the scenario above, in milliseconds, clicking a button would grab the current coordinates, change the z-index, then put the page back where it was with no visible change to the user. It would appear the same as just setting the z-index of the two elements, as window.scroll is instant. If you are looking for a more animated approach I can put one together for you. I've confirmed that the code you had pasted works, so I'm now trying to help you apply it and/or some additional code to your own situation.

Comment: I've changed the answer to the simple instant scrolling functions, and some examples for animated scrolling functions. Good luck with your solution.

Comment: Thank you for great reply! If you may, please provide a link to information on other approaches, I would like to get better knowledge on the subject.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a really easy solution using jquery. If you think my answer is helpful, please mark it as such. I've run out of ideas :)